# Division algorithm for polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

When we do the division algorithm for polynomials, how do we figure out $ca^{-1}$; i.e., for the problem where $f(x)= 3x^2+2$ and $g(x)= 4x^4 + 2x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x + 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$.

Here, $a= 3$ and $c=4$ but how $c(a^{-1})= 3(2)= 6$. Where did the $2$ come from? Also when we are multiplying $c(a^{-1})(x^k-j)f(x)$, which in this case is $6x^2$. $(f(x))= 4x^4+5x^2$. how do we get this?

Comment: I think you are asking how to find the reciprocal (multiplicative inverse) of numbers in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, or more generally in the finite fields given by integers modulo a prime $p$.  The short answer is the Euclidean algorithm can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got it now its the multiplicative inverse. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the modulus is small, you should be able to do this by trial and error.  For example, $x=4^{-1}$ modulo $7$ means
$$4x\equiv1\pmod7\ ,$$
and you should easily be able to see that this is the same as
$$4x\equiv8\pmod7\ ,$$
giving $x=2$.

Another example: find $5^{-1}$ modulo $11$.  We have
$$5x\equiv1\equiv45\pmod{11}\ ,$$
so $x=9$.

If it's too hard to do by trial and error you can use the following.  To find $x=a^{-1}$ modulo $m$, we want
$$ax\equiv1\pmod m\ ,$$
that is,
$$ax-my=1\ ,$$
and I expect you know how to use the **Euclidean algorithm** to find $x$ (and also $y$, though for this problem it is irrelevant).

Comment: thanks a lot. yes i know how to use the euclidean algorithm